# Auto-add BCC address to notmuch/message-mode messages

Tags: gnus, email, notmuch

I use GNUs for most of my email needs, but also have notmuch for rapid search of my inbox. Trouble is, when I choose a message in that notmuch search, it doesn't open it with gnus but with its own whatever message-mode spinoff called `Message[Notmuch]`. In GNUS I have an automatically added BCC address (my "sent-mail" inbox, which is downloaded across devices to sync what I've sent). How can I get the same automatic BCC added to anything I send in reply with `Message[Notmuch]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working answer by using `customize-variable` `message-default-mail-headers` and adding: `"Bcc: address@place.com
"`

It looks like this in the end (in my emacs-custom.el):

```
'(message-default-mail-headers "Bcc: address@place.com"
")
```

Note that it is required for each mail header line to end in a newline.